# Write stdout stream to file

Tags: file, go, stream, stdout

I am running an external process via `exec.Command()` and I want the stdout from the command to be printed as well as written to file, in real time (similar to using `tee` from a command-line) .

I can achieve this with a scanner and a writer:

```
cmd := exec.Command("mycmd")
cmdStdOut, _ := cmd.StdoutPipe()

s := bufio.NewScanner(cmdStdOut)
f, _ := os.Create("stdout.log")
w := bufio.NewWriter(f)

go func() {
    for s.Scan(){
        t := s.Text()
        fmt.Println(t)
        fmt.Fprint(w, t)
        w.Flush()    
    }
}
```

Is there a more idiomatic way to do this that avoids clobbering `Scan` and `Flush`?

Comment: `cmd.Stdout = f`

Comment: But don't forget to handle errors...

Comment: Yep, I ignored stderr / errors for brevity. I'm now also wondering about the case where I want to do something with the stdout stream in conjunction with writing it (eg, like tee). Perhaps I'll update the question.

Comment: io.MultiWriter plus io.Pipe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assign a multiwriter to the commmand's stdout that writes to a file and to a pipe. You can then use the pipe's read end to follow the output.

This example behaves similar to the `tee` tool:

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    var f *os.File // e.g. os.Create, os.Open

    r, w := io.Pipe()
    defer w.Close()

    cmd := exec.Command("mycmd")
    cmd.Stdout = io.MultiWriter(w, f)

    // do something with the output while cmd is running by reading from r
    go io.Copy(os.Stdout, r) 

    cmd.Run()
}
```

Alternative with StdoutPipe:

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    var f *os.File

    cmd := exec.Command("date")
    stdout, _ := cmd.StdoutPipe()

    go io.Copy(io.MultiWriter(f, os.Stdout), stdout)

    cmd.Run()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring errors for brevity. As stated by other answers, you could use *io.MultiWriter* in an *io.Copy*, but when you are dealing with *stdout* of *exec.Cmd*, you need to be aware of *Wait* closing the pipes as soon as the command terminates, as stated by the documentation (https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd.StdoutPipe).

> Wait will close the pipe after seeing the command exit, so most callers need not close the pipe themselves. It is thus incorrect to call Wait before all reads from the pipe have completed.

Ignoring this could lead to some portions of the output not being read, and is therefore lost. Instead, do not use *Run*, but instead use *Start* and *Wait*. eg.

```golang
package main

import (
    "io"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("date")
    stdout, _ := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    f, _ := os.Create("stdout.log")

    cmd.Start()
    io.Copy(io.MultiWriter(f, os.Stdout), stdout)
    cmd.Wait()
}
```

This will ensure everything is read from *stdout* and close all pipes afterwards.

Comment: Why this ensures everything is read? What if Wait closes the pipe before io.Copy manages to copy everything out of the pipe? So what ensures that this is not so?