# Run program w/ exec.Command redirecting stdout to /dev/null

Tags: bash, go

I am translating my script from bash to go and unfortunately I am not able to make pass command work. When I run the bash one I receive a window to provide my password to the pass manager.

Here is part of my go code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

func run_command(command *exec.Cmd) string {
    attach_json, err := command.Output()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
        // os.Exit(0)
    }
    fmt.Println(attach_json)
    return string(attach_json)
}

email := "xyz@abc.com"
cmd_emamil := "GoJira/api-token:" + email
pass_cmd := exec.Command("pass", cmd_emamil, "> /dev/null")
pass_cmd := exec.Command("pass", cmd_emamil)
run_command(pass_cmd)
```

Comment: `exec.Command` is not the shell. You cannot use shell syntax there (`"> /dev/null"`), unless you invoke `sh` or `bash`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48926982/write-stdout-stream-to-file

Answer (score 3):

In the shell command `pass >/dev/null`, `>/dev/null` is not an argument to `pass`; instead, it's an instruction to the shell, telling it to replace file descriptor 1 (stdout) with a handle on `/dev/null` before `pass` is started.

When you use `exec.Command()` there *is* no shell, so you can't use shell syntax. Instead, assign the file you want stdout to be redirected to to the `Stdout` of your `exec.Command`.

```
devnull, err := os.OpenFile(os.DevNull, os.O_WRONLY, 0755)
if err != nil { panic(err) }

cmd_email := "GoJira/api-token:" + email
pass_cmd := exec.Command("pass", cmd_email)
pass_cmd.Stdout = devnull
```

Comment: Instead of `devnull`, directly use `io.Discard`

Comment: At the very least, `os.DevNull` instead of `"/dev/null/"`

Comment: @p9sh, my concern (the reason I didn't write the answer that way initially) is that unless `exec.Command` has a specific optimization for the case, `io.Discard` will make Go code read the output and ignore it, instead of letting the OS itself ignore it on write with nothing ever needing to make a corresponding read call.